# How to insert multiple record using single form texarea with nodejs and mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I wanna insert record in textarea with formart

```
name1|url2
name2|url2
name3|url3
```

My schemas collections

```
name:String,
url:String,
```

please help me, thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

You can use:-

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';

var data1={

```
name:'name1',

url:'url1'
```

};

var data2={

```
name:'name2',

url:'url2'
```

};

var data3={

```
name:'name3',

url:'url3'
```

};

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {

```
if(err!=null){
     return console.log(err.message)
}

//insertOne
db.collection("App").insertOne(data1,function (err,data) {

    if(err!=null){

        return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(data.ops[0]);
});
```

//insertMany

var Data=[data1,data2,data3];

db.collection("App").insertMany(Data,forceServerObjectId=true,function (err,data) {

```
    if(err!=null){

        return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(data.ops);
});
db.close();
```

});

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: thanks you, but i wanna insert record from textarea form